# How can I fix IPv6 not forwarding traffic correctly between interfaces?

Tags: networking, openvpn, ipv6, opensuse, firewalld

I have two OpenSUSE servers, one with IPv6 and IPv4 while the other only has IPv4 capablities. The two of them are connected with OpenVPN and can communicate using IPv6 through the tunnel just fine.

The setup is the following:

```
Server A (IPv6 and IPv4)
  It has assigned a /64 IPv6 subnet, let's say it is: 2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::/64
  ens3 interface:
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1/112
    fe80::***/64 (link-local)
    (Also tried using the /64 mask as shown below instead of the /112 mask. Same result)
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1/64

  tun0 interface:
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1/112
    fe80::***/64 (link-local)

  Routes:
    ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::/112 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:0/112 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    fe80::/64 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    default via fe80::1 dev ens3 metric 1024 pref medium

Server B (IPv4 only on non-tun interfaces)
  eno1 interface:
    fe80::***/64 (link-local)
  tun0 interface:
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:8000/112
    fe80::***/64 (link-local)

  routes (ip -6 route):
    ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:0/112 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    fe80::/64 dev eno1 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
    fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
    default dev tun0 metric 1024 pref medium
    
    (Alternatively, explicitly define the route IP. It has the same result)
    default via 2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1 dev tun0 metric 1024 pref medium
```

Forwarding on IPv6 is apparently enabled as per `sysctl`:

```
# sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
# sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.ens3.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.forwarding = 1
```

with this setup I can, from server **B** ping and connect to both `2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1` (tun0 address on server **A**) so the VPN tunnel works; And I can also ping and connect to `2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1` (ens3 address on server **A**) but if i try to connect to any other ipv6 address (for example `wget -6 google.com`) it will only work from Server **A** but not on server **B**.

Traceroute from **B** shows stars past the first hop, as if the routes are wrong.

```
1  2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1 (2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1)  30.739 ms  30.755 ms  30.758 ms
2  * * *
[...]
30 * * *
```

***¿How could I fix this IPv6 connectivity issue?***

Comment: What does tcpdump show about where the packets go (or don't)?

Comment: Do you have any firewall on server A? If yes, what's IPv6 forwarding setup?

Comment: There is `firewalld` on both server, however I've tried disabling the firewall firs by stopping `firewalld` and then dropping all firewall rules with the same result.

Comment: What does `ip route get 2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1` on Server B show?

Comment: What happens if you set Server A to IPv4 only? The IPV6 subnet mask perhaps should be /112 instead of /64. See also [Build a OpenVPN server on Ubuntu to provide a IPv6 tunnel over IPv4](https://techblog.synagila.com/2016/02/24/build-a-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-to-provide-a-ipv6-tunnel-over-ipv4/).

Comment: @dirkt `ip -6 route get [address]` retuns the following line: `2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:1 from :: dev tun0 prto kernel src 2aFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::1:8000 metric 256 pref medium` (does it means route-to-A lies on tun0 interface?)

Comment: @harrymc just tried putting `ens3` ipv6 address mask to /64, same result. Since that configuration "makes more sense" I will be keeping it. Editting OP now to reflect the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need `proxy_ndp`.** You now have the following IPv6 configuration:

- External router (you don’t control it): Other stuff, `[2001:0DB8::1]/64` on `eth0`
- Server A: `[2001:0DB8::2]/112` on `eth0`, `[2001:0DB8::1:1]/112` on `tun0`
- Server B: `[2001:0DB8::1:2]/112` on `tun0`, other stuff

You can immediately see the problem: The devices do not agree about the subnet size. The external router expects all of `[2001:0DB8::0]/64` to be *directly reachable* via `eth0`. If it tries to reach a host that is coincidentally part of `[2001:0DB8::1:0]/112`, it’ll never receive a reply to its Neighbor Discovery Protocol requests, because the host isn’t on the local network.

This is where `proxy_ndp` comes into play: It’ll make server A act as a proxy for NDP requests to specific hosts, all of which you manually have to add:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1
ip -6 neigh add proxy 2001:0DB8::1:2 dev eth0
```

This instructs the PC to answer to NDP requests for `2001:0DB8::1:2` that arrive on `eth0`.

IIRC you also need to use `[2001:0DB8::1]/64` on both `eth0` and `tun0`, but I’m not entirely sure. This would of course mean to need to add explicit routes on server A for every IPv6 address because of the ambiguousness.

**A setup like this can work, but I don’t really recommend it.** Just use IPv6 NAT and Unique Local Addressing on the VPN network. Yes, NAT was supposed to go away. No, it’s here to stay. :-)

Comment: Adding the neighbour manually eventually worked, and i could "hack" together something on openvpn to add the neighbour on connection, but it just feels off doing it this way, on IPv4 it "just works". Are there any other options to get the same result? like "neighbouring" whole subnets? In any case I'll probably award you the answer since you solved the issue as asked.

Comment: (using another comment since im over the char limit) Why is it not recommended to route a subnet of the /64 address and using NAT instead? The purpose is having globaly routable address at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: IPv4 has the exact same problem with the exact same solution: `proxy_arp`. There appears to be a daemon that can automate `proxy_ndp` somewhat. // From personal experience, I find that `proxy_ndp` is not reliable enough. IPv6 NAT, however, is. You don’t need a globally routable address. You need a reachable address.

Comment: For any address within my /64 subnet, the router attached to `ens3` will perform a neighbour discover since it presumes the address is directly attached, for it to not need a discovery, the router would need a (static?) route to the `::1:0/112` subnet *via* the `::0:0/64` address (as in IPv4).

Comment: Yes, via server A, not just any address.